# How to look up from dictionary inside update statement?

Tags: kdb

I have a table 't' and a dictionary 'lookup':

```
t:([] date:2018.01.01 + til 5; a:`a`b`c`d`e)

lookup:((2018.01.01 + til 5),'`a`b`c`d`e)!(1000*til 5)
```

So lookup takes a list of date and symbol as key, e.g.:

```
lookup[(2018.01.03;`c)] /returns 2000j
```

And if I want to use the dictionary inside an update statement, that generally works:

```
update b:lookup[(2018.01.03;`c)] from t
update b:lookup[(last date;last a)] from t
```

However, I am not able to use it for the imho most obvious use case: to lookup for the specific row values. This here would intuitively be the easiest, but returns an error ("ERROR: 'length"):

```
update b:lookup[(date;a)] from t
```

Also thought of using the index, but that didn't work either:

```
update b:lookup[(date[i];a[i])] from t
```

Came across the problem pattern a few times already, would be good if there's a straight-forward solution to it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It think it should be

```
update b:lookup[flip (date;a)] from t
```

the `flip` will convert the 2 column vectors to a single list, which can then be used for the lookup:

```
flip (t`date;t`a)
((2018.01.01;`a);(2018.01.02;`b);(2018.01.03;`c);(2018.01.04;`d);(2018.01.05;`e))
```

**Alternatively**, you can use a keyed table and simply `lj` the table `t` with the `lookup2` keyed table :

```
lookup2:( [date:(2018.01.01 + til 5); a:`a`b`c`d`e] b:1000*til 5)
t lj lookup2
```

Answer (score 3):

building on @nyi's answer. 
An alternative to flip is to use a join each ,' 
this will be slightly faster, but could be noticeable on larger data sets

```
q)\ts update b:lookup[flip (date;a)] from 1000000#t
904 101750064
q)\ts update b:lookup[date,'a] from 1000000#t
343 101750064
```